# Can I Add/Update/Delete policy configurations using the .NET SDK?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, tfs-sdk

I know that there is a REST API for [these operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/configurations?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

On the GitHttpClient class though, I can only find a method that GETs policy configurations (GetPolicyConfigurationsAsync)

Is there anything on the **SDK** that allows Add/Update/Delete or I'll have to create and make the http request  myself?

I'm using Nuget package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client.16.153.0

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I Add/Update/Delete policy configurations using the .NET SDK?

To achieve these action, please check the [PolicyHttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.policy.webapi.policyhttpclient?view=azure-devops-dotnet) class.

[UpdatePolicyConfigurationAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.policy.webapi.policyhttpclient.updatepolicyconfigurationasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet): this method can for you make some **updates** into policy configuration.

[DeletePolicyConfigurationAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.policy.webapi.policyhttpclient.deletepolicyconfigurationasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet): **Delete** the policy configuration.

For Add, I think this could be also achieved with the **UpdatePolicyConfigurationAsync** method.